# Fetching columns dynamically from dataframe , column name would come in variable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am not able to fetch values for given dynamic columns. Any help ?

```
var dynamicColumns = "col(\"one\"),col(\"two\"),col(\"three\")"

dataFrame.select(dynamicColumns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use names alone:

```scala
val dynamicColumns = Seq("one", "two", "three")
dataFrame.select(dynamicColumns map col: _*)
```

and if you don't have control over the format, use regexp to extract names first

```scala
val dynamicColumns = "col(\"one\"),col(\"two\"),col(\"three\")"
val p = """(?<=col\(").+?(?="\))""".r

dataFrame.select(p.findAllIn(dynamicColumns) map col toSeq: _*)
```